# @JmsListener - hitting the destined queue continuously

Tags: java, listener, spring-jms

I have a spring boot application with JMS messaging included. The receiver and the connection Factory is as below,The problem I am having is the listener always looks the queue and prints in logs, Logs attached for reference. It should trigger the process() when there is a message in the queue.

Any help appreciated

```
    package uk.gov.hmrc.cds.dmscaseemulator.receiver;
    
    import javax.jms.JMSException;
    import javax.jms.Message;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
    import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    
    import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
    import uk.gov.hmrc.cds.dmscaseemulator.bo.DMSMessageProcessBO;
    
    @Service
    @Slf4j
    public class DMSQReceiver   {
        
    
        
        @Value("${queue.DMS_Q}")
        private String listeningQ;
        
        @Autowired DMSMessageProcessBO processBo;
        
        @JmsListener(destination="${queue.DMS_Q}", containerFactory = "myFactory")
        public void recv(Message message) throws JMSException{
            try{
                log.info("Listening to : {} ", listeningQ);
                processBo.process(message);
            }catch(JMSException ex){
                log.error("ERROR IN DMS Case Emulator while receiving " + listeningQ +". ERROR IS : ", ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
    
    package uk.gov.hmrc.cds.dmscaseemulator.config;
    
    import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
    
    import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
    import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
    import org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory;
    import org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
    import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
    import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter;
    import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageType;
    
    @Configuration
    @EnableJms
    public class JMSConfig {
        
         @Bean
          public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(
              ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
              DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
            configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
            return factory;
          }
    }
```

```
20:23:37.281 [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] INFO  u.g.h.c.d.receiver.DMSQReceiver - Listening to : DMS.QA.CTRL_MGMT_EXPORT 
20:23:37.282 [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] DEBUG u.g.h.c.d.b.c.ControlTypeResolver - Found control type
20:23:37.282 [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] DEBUG u.g.h.c.d.b.c.ControlTypeResolver - Returning control type value : 3 
20:23:37.283 [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] INFO  u.g.h.c.d.bo.DMSMessageProcessBO - Control Type is: 3 
20:23:37.290 [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] INFO  u.g.h.c.d.receiver.DMSQReceiver - Listening to : DMS.QA.CTRL_MGMT_EXPORT 
20:23:37.291 [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] DEBUG u.g.h.c.d.b.c.ControlTypeResolver - Found control type
20:23:37.291 [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] DEBUG u.g.h.c.d.b.c.ControlTypeResolver - Returning control type value : 3 
20:23:37.292 [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] INFO  u.g.h.c.d.bo.DMSMessageProcessBO - Control Type is: 3
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Clearly your listener is being triggered by each message; it's emitting `Listening to : DMS.QA.CTRL_MGMT_EXPORT ` (that said, it seems pointless to keep logging the queue name you are listening to). It also appears to be hitting your process method `DMSMessageProcessBO`.

Comment: The issue is, irrespective of the message there in the queue the listener keeps triggering. This needs to be fixed. Only when the message arrives in the queue, the listener and process method should be executed

Comment: But they are. You received 2 messages in the log above. If you are seeing the same message redelivered, you must be throwing some exception other than JmsException.

Comment: DEBUG logging will help.

Comment: when the message count in the queue is 0, we are seeing the logs, that's the issue

Comment: What JMS broker? Most have a prefetch. E.g. ActiveMQ has a default of 1000. So while the broker might say there are zero, there might be some sitting in the JMS client to be processed, having been prefetched. Log the message instead of just the queue name.

Comment: IBM MQ. I logged the message and could see duplicates.

Comment: So why are you importing ActiveMQConnectionFactory. What you are suggesting is impossible unless you are throwing an exception.